# Start Angular routes with :id: Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an app that solely relies on the client that's loading the application. The URL would look something like this:

```
https://domain/#/:clientName/dashboard
https://domain/#/:clientName/details
etc.
```

Dashboard, details, etc. all are lazy-loaded modules. I have a few questions about this setup:

1. Do I need to necessarily have ":clientName" as part of every path in app-routing.module?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':clientName', redirectTo: ':clientName/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: ':clientName/dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    },
    {
        path: ':clientName/details',
        loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then(m => m.DetailsModule)
    },
    
    {path: '**', component: 404Component},
];
```

Can't I somehow have a base with the clientName that never changes?

2. Everytime I do:

```
router.navigate
or
router.navigateByUrl
```

I need to provide the full path including the "clientName", which feels like an unnecessary step. If I only provide the path without ClientName, then the clientName is removed from the URL, which I don't want.

So is it possible to append everything after https://domain/#/:clientName/ automatically without me always adding clientName as part of every URL navigation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

You can make a component for the `:clientName` path and just put a `<router-outlet>` in the html. Declare your relative paths inside the `children` array of the `:clientName` path.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':clientName',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ClientComponent
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'details',
        loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then(m => m.DetailsModule)
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', component: 404Component },
];
```

**Question 2**

You can perform your routing from inside this new component using `relativeTo: this.route`

```js
@Component({...})
class ClientComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  loadDashboard() {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```

If you want to navigate from other components, consider creating a service that wraps the Router service (something like clientRouter), adding the prefix to the url, or just triggering functions within the ClientComponent via observables. I have no idea what your app looks like so I can't really tell you how to implement that.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction.